# Do I really just have three colors?

Tags: colors, angular-material, material-design

I have an Angular Material application.

The application has a button to click. I want it to look nice so I make it `<button mat-button>Hello Button</button>`.

Now I want to make the button show up in the "accent" color of my theme so I change it to `<button mat-button color="accent">Button</button>`. Works great.

Now I want to make the button show up as a slightly darker version of the "accent" color so I change it to `<button color="accent A600">Slightly Darker Button</button>`. No, that's definitely not it.

I read around Stack Overflow a bit and try some things and find that I can create a CSS class and apply that class to my button, but there's not really a way to say "make this my theme's accent color but a bit darker." It's just straight up hardcoding a color value.

As far as I can tell, Angular Material has "palettes" that I can't access in any meaningful way.

My question: Is it really true that button colors in Angular Material can only be "primary" or "accent" or "warn" or bypass the palette system altogether? What do I have to do to access the various lighter and darker shades on the palettes?

Or more directly, what goes in the `[color]` attribute? `<button mat-button [color]="what-goes-here?">Slightly Darker Button</button>`?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest thing to change button color is to make something like this:

Inside your HTML:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="something">Click on me</button>
```

color="something" will generate a class then you will be able to make this in CSS:

```
.mat-success{
  color: yellow;
  background: purple;
}
```

Comment: Okay, that's a good start. I don't get why there's so much documentation about the various colors on the "palette" in Material Design itself, that I don't seem to have access to though. Are these just not supported by Angular Material? https://material.io/design/color/the-color-system.html#color-usage-and-palettes

Comment: Someone who uses Angular longer than me could probably answer to your question :D I found in the Angular Material documentation that you can theme your custom component https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components but i think its just too much hassle and its just faster to do that in CSS.